# Disposal when chaining Observables from async

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Assume I have the following `Observable`.  (Note that the parsing logic lives in a different layer, and should be testable, so it must remain a separate method.  Note also that the real loop is parsing XML and has various branching and exception handling).

```
IObservable<string> GetLinesAsync(StreamReader r)
{
    return Observable.Create<string>(subscribeAsync: async (observer, ct) =>
    {
        //essentially force a continuation/callback to illustrate my problem
        await Task.Delay(5);

        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            string readLine = await r.ReadLineAsync();
            if (readLine == null)
                break;

            observer.OnNext(readLine);
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to use this, for example with another `Observable` that produces the `StreamReader`, as in the below, but in any case I cannot get the disposal to work.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ReactiveTest()
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "win.ini");

    var source1 = Observable.Using(
    () => File.OpenRead(filePath),   
        readFile => Observable.Using(() => new StreamReader(readFile),
            reader => Observable.Return(reader)
        )
    );

    //"GetLinesAsync" already exists.  How can I use it?
    var combined = source1
        .SelectMany(GetLinesAsync);

    int count = await combined.Count();

}
```

If you run this a few times (e.g. with breakpoints, etc), you should see that it blows up because the TextReader is closed.  (In my actual problem it happens sporadically on `ReadLineAsync` but the `Task.Delay` makes it happen much more easily).  Apparently the asynchronous nature causes the first observable to dispose the stream, and only after that does the continuation occur, and of course at that point the stream is already closed.

So:

1. is the first disposable with the usings set up right?  I tried it other ways (see below*)
2. Is that the right way to do an async Observable (i.e. GetLinesAsync)?  Is there anything else I need to do for that?
3. Is this a proper way to chain the observables together?  Assume the `GetLinesAsync` already exists and if possible its signature shouldn't be changed (e.g. to take in `IObservable<StreamReader>`)
4. if this is the right way to glue together the observables, is there any way to get it working with `async` usage?

*this was another way I set up the first observerable

```
var source3 = Observable.Create<StreamReader>(observer =>
{
    FileStream readFile = File.OpenRead(filePath);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(readFile);

    observer.OnNext(reader);
    observer.OnCompleted();

    return new CompositeDisposable(readFile, reader);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You really need to make good use of the `Defer` and `Using` operators here.

`Using` is specifically for the case where you have a disposable resource that you would like to have created and finally disposed of when the subscription starts and completes respectively.

`Defer` is a way to ensure that you always create a new pipeline whenever you have a new subscription ([read more on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229160(v=vs.103).aspx))

Your second approach is the way to go. You got this 100% right:

```
Observable.Using(
    () => File.OpenRead(filePath),
    readFile =>
        Observable.Using(
            () => new StreamReader(readFile),
            reader =>
```

This will open and dispose of the resources at the correct time for each.

It's what goes before this block of code and what's after the `reader =>` that you need to fix.

After the `reader =>` is this:

```
Observable
    .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => reader.ReadLineAsync()))
    .Repeat()
    .TakeWhile(x => x != null)));
```

That's the idiomatic way for Rx to read from a stream until completion.

The "before" block is just another `Defer` to ensure that you compute `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "win.ini")` with each new subscriber. It's not necessary in this case because we know that the `filePath` won't change, but it's good practice and quite probably crucial when this value can change.

Here's the full code:

```
public async Task ReactiveTest()
{
    IObservable<string> combined =
        Observable.Defer(() =>
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "win.ini");
            return
                Observable.Using(
                    () => File.OpenRead(filePath),
                    readFile =>
                        Observable.Using(
                            () => new StreamReader(readFile),
                            reader =>
                                Observable
                                    .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => reader.ReadLineAsync()))
                                    .Repeat()
                                    .TakeWhile(x => x != null)));
        });

    int count = await combined.Count();
}
```

I've tested it and it works superbly.

Given that you have a fixed signature for `GetLines` you can do this:

```
public IObservable<string> GetLines(StreamReader reader)
{
    return Observable
        .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => reader.ReadLineAsync()))
        .Repeat()
        .TakeWhile(x => x != null);
}

public async Task ReactiveTest()
{
    IObservable<string> combined =
        Observable.Defer(() =>
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "win.ini");
            return
                Observable.Using(
                    () => File.OpenRead(filePath),
                    readFile =>
                        Observable.Using(
                            () => new StreamReader(readFile),
                            GetLines));
        });

    int count = await combined.Count();
}
```

It also works and was tested.

Comment: Can you devote some time to explaining what `Defer` is doing for this code? I'm having to infer quite a lot. I understand there is a paradigm shift going here but am having trouble describing why it is necessary. Please expand the answer to include more justification.

Comment: @Gusdor - I assume you're particularly asking about the `Defer`/`Repeat` combination? This is incredibly important as the `Repeat` on it's own just repeats the value produced by the preceding observable. With the `Defer` it re-runs the observable thus creating a new value and not just repeating the previous value. I must admit I've never understood how it does this,but it works that way.

Comment: I've had a play and it the 2nd (innermost) `Defer` appears to be removable. The result of `ReadLineAsync` seems to change every time, even without defer. Is that going to cause unexpected behaviour down the line?

Comment: Thanks, this is in line with what I was expecting (Defer).  However, the real version isn't so simple as to be broken out of the loop (i.e. reduced to `Observable.FromAsync(() => reader.ReadLineAsync())`.  Keeping to the original function signatures, then, is it

```var combined = source1.SelectMany(reader => Observable.Defer(() => GetLines(reader));```

?

Comment: (I ask because ```var combined = source1.SelectMany(reader => Observable.Defer(() => GetLines(reader));``` still results in accessing a closed stream)

Comment: @MarkSowul - I tested the code that I posted and it worked fine. Have you changed the code in any way?

Comment: @Gusdor - If it's working without it, that's fine. The `FromAsync` call is probably doing the same as `Defer` in this case. It shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: I can't use a version that does all the work in one Observable.  That would easily solve the original problem, because I could just do `Observable.Create(observer => using(StreamReader reader ...) { while(...) { observer.OnNext(await reader.ReadLineAsync()); } }`  Given the preexistence of a method whose signature is `IObservable<string> GetLines(StreamReader reader)`, is it possible to use such a method and if so, how?  I tried adapting it with Defer / SelectMany (as in previous comment) and it failed the same way.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `Observable.Create(observer => ...` as defined in your comment - it's not cancellable. You should use my definition. But, if you have to, then I'll give you the solution. Give me a couple of ticks to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Note that it is cancellable if it uses (observer, ct), but that's an orthogonal point. My actual loop is not so easily reduced to Observable primitives, so Observable.Create is pretty much necessary.  I will clarify the question a bit more, but every time I think I have something that works for real, it mostly works but sporadically fails.

Comment: Note that I don't think any of the "single observable" solutions ever have given me trouble.  So, if I don't use two observables (for example using the original GetLinesAsync in the question with your `Using`) then it's not an issue.  I'm more or less giving up on the two Observables situation (the purpose was for testing) because I can't keep spending time on this problem.  I'm guessing there's something dodgy going on with the subscription, because I would think that the `IObservable<StreamReader>` shouldn't be disposing until the inner IObservable finishes too.

Comment: @MarkSowul - You say "Note that it is cancellable if it uses (observer, ct)" - but where is that in your question? You use of `reader => Observable.Return(reader)` is where your code is falling over - the `Return` calls `OnNext` and then `OnCompleted` which is why the stream is closed.

Comment: It isn't in my question, because it isn't relevant to it, so I wanted to avoid adding noise.  If I add the cancellation, it still doesn't affect the premature disposal.  So if the Observable.Return is the issue, is there any way to get it to work as two Observables?  That has always been the question: how do I chain two IObservables together when the second one is Async?  Observable.Return works fine if the second one is synchronous.

Comment: @MarkSowul - Yes, that's what my answer was showing you to do. The update I put in 22 hours ago shows you how to do two queries. What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure if this helps illustrate, but it makes the Source depend on the Parser (we have multiple parser implementations and multiple source implementations)...  (cont.)

Comment: The goal is this: https://www.planttext.com/?text=PP91Ry8m38Nl_HKMf_ImIZkFLKn3GXoc8UXjsi6btgWKqifn4HtYlwyaq94ibyXFzfVdfyoi84ktrqbLVpEsErZ0AO7XjCYM-4DZIVfvibovSbgioNPQSZZ1yhqSb0EMclvarwOAEigQi286TbVw1EV9f-FQfkCjZToDAsFSE9_3WiJtp55GtO7GeEv_Y1zlh9UR0AesCCm07N7VQeePsOOqRUKDJQ_ycfdpdQRPQzCPKUdr2I4heTzYKAwMrO6u_kfZEA1k3DqJmYGl11_cI8X32ndXiW-vnyMgjncv_YVxsO2Hd26PaQakV-0N

Comment: But the proposed solution results in this: https://www.planttext.com/?text=TPBDJiCm48JlVefLJxO4aJXJeY8GLGy8rEQ6E6oI1IAvJkIVgg7gkvFQQLgdr0TRE_9-ux4zCnQrTMl9okfRO_C3SzWnw4Q3sf3-a9YJV9WitdqvpPPadBGfx63nbdVA1dD99zblunbjxPAm90tQB-8UzfDFppMrqmKDt9Klh-7cPCE6PxGuoFp5gM9wChdvjpdj8vnv-maLolQNzDtn38z70NYbeBC3skAwaHJRSv6iI59XNr6rFB0JdrU8vAbsodBH-rWoDiwPTKeVbMz8Lr_j60ueQqNdXFW53eJm20DXVDanWmsNVPi6L1p_cXfwHZakvD0RCTWUs8nKUVXDVm00

Comment: @MarkSowul - You cannot have an observable return a disposable resource without it having the issue you're experiencing. You must do it using `.Using`. It sounds like your real-world requirements are more complicated than you've posted in your question. I appreciate that you tried to avoid adding noise to your question, but I think it's relevant. You need to provide a [mcve] of what you're doing. You haven't met the minimal requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that your sequences return a single item, the reader. Making use of the reader, requires the file stream to be open. The file stream is unfortunately closed immediately after the stream reader is created:

1. `StreamReader reader` is created
2. `OnNext(reader)` is called
3. `using` block exits, disposing of stream
4. OnComplete is called, terminating the subscription

Oops!

To fix this, you must tie the lifetime of the `StreamReader` to the lifetime of the *consumer* rather than the producer. The original fault occurs because `Observable.Using` disposes the resource as soon as `OnCompleted` is called upon the source.

```
// Do not dispose of the reader when it is created
var readerSequence = Observable.Return(new StreamReader(ms));

var combined = readerSequence
    .Select(reader =>
    {
        return Observable.Using(() => reader, resource => GetLines(resource));
    })
    .Concat();
```

I'm not a massive fan of this as you now rely on your consumer cleaning up the each `StreamReader` but I'm yet to formulate a better way!

Comment: Thanks.  That is an apt summary of the dispose issue.  The problem is, as mentioned (or implied), these are separate pieces, and folding in GetLines is not a solution (GetLines was just an example; there are multiple different implementations of how we want to parse the results of the TextReader).  Also note that GetLines is an Observable already so ToObservable doesn't work.

Comment: Also note that it's the async that blows it up; but for that, the "onNext" doesn't complete until the inner observable completes

Comment: @MarkSowul I've edited the answer to provide a working solution.

Comment: What makes you think that "The file stream is unfortunately closed immediately after the stream reader is created."?

Comment: @Enigmativity From the snippets in the question: reader is created -> `OnNext(reader)` is called -> `using` block exits, disposing of stream -> `OnComplete` is called

Comment: @Gusdor - Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: @MarkSowul Can you confirm if this solution meets your requirements since my update? I have verified it using your replication conditions.

Comment: Hi Gusdor -- I have upvoted the answer, but shifting the responsibility of disposal to the consumer as you rightly point out isn't going to make the cut.  It's okay for simple scenarios but unfortunately based on the answers here what I want seems impossible, or maybe we're all missing something.

Comment: @MarkSowul are you able to add the additional constraints to the questions? I would be great to see a non-trivial example of usage so we can have a play. Hopefully, the reasons that this answer is not suitable would be explicitly outlined in your edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

So far this is the only thing that has worked while allowing me to keep using GetLinesAsync:

```
//"GetLinesAsync" already exists.  How can I use it?


[TestMethod]
public async Task ReactiveTest2()
{
    var combined2 = Observable.Create<string>(async observer =>
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "win.ini");

        using (FileStream readFile = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(readFile))
            {
                await GetLinesAsync(reader)
                    .ForEachAsync(result => observer.OnNext(result));
            }
        }
    });


    int count = await combined2.Count();
}
```

This does not work reliably:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ReactiveTest3()
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "win.ini");

    var source1 = Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Using(
        () => File.OpenRead(filePath),
        readFile => Observable.Using(() => new StreamReader(readFile),
            reader => Observable.Return(reader)
        )
    ));

    //"GetLines" already exists.  How can I use it?
    var combined = source1      
            .SelectMany(reader => Observable.Defer(() => GetLinesAsync(reader)));

    int count = await combined.Count();

}
```

It only seems to work if there's one Observable, as per Enigmativity's solution:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ReactiveTest4()
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "win.ini");

    var source1 = Observable.Using(
        () => File.OpenRead(filePath),
        readFile => Observable.Using(() => new StreamReader(readFile),
            reader => GetLinesAsync(reader)
        )
    );

    int count = await source1.Count();

}
```

But I haven't found a way to preserve the separation between the two Observables (which I do for layering and unit test purposes) and have it work right, so I don't consider the question answered.